# Possibly to create a library on webpart install?

Tags: 2010, web-part

I'd like to create a library that my webpart uses to store documents.  I would prefer to have this library only be visible through my webpart and by admins.  Is this possible?

If so, how would I go about creating my library when the webpart is installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "installed" I presume you mean when the feature containing the web part is activated. In this case you can do this programmatically through the feature receiver, or declaratively. This subject is documented extensively [elsewhere](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/allenwang/how-to-create-custom-content-type-and-list-instance-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010).

You can set permissions on the list to limit who can see it. In your web part you can use elevated priviledges to access the list, for example using the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges method.